# Python dataframe subtract datetime for each unique id with previous datetime and put into seperate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have a DataFrame as such:

```
ID                Departuredate Arrivaldate
000afb96ded6677c  2014-02-08    2014-09-08        
                  2015-10-22    2015-10-26        
                  2017-02-19    2017-02-26              
                  ..

ffea14e87a4e1269  2020-02-18    2020-02-23        
                  2020-07-18    2020-07-23
```

I need to find the date difference from each trip with the previous trip from that specific id and put into column next to it like this:

```
    ID            Departuredate Arrivaldate  Time_Difference_Between_Trips
000afb96ded6677c  2014-02-08    2014-09-08   0 (days) # 0 days because there is no previous trip    
                  2015-10-22    2015-10-26   X (days) # 2015-10-22 - 2014-09-08   
                  2017-02-19    2017-02-26   X (days) # 2017-02-19 - 2015-10-26              
                  ..

ffea14e87a4e1269  2020-02-18    2020-02-23  X (days) # 0 days because there is no previous trip    
                  2020-07-18    2020-07-23  X (days) # 2020-07-18 - 2020-02-23
```

Comment: Can you post the actual dataframe instead of posting the pics? check - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: @Nk03 i posted the actual dataframe sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`groupby shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-shift) + [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna):

```
df['Time_Difference_Between_Trips'] = (
    (df['Departuredate'] - df.groupby('ID')['Arrivaldate'].shift())
        .fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=0))
)
```

```
                 ID Departuredate Arrivaldate Time_Difference_Between_Trips
0  000afb96ded6677c    2014-02-08  2014-09-08                        0 days
1  000afb96ded6677c    2015-10-22  2015-10-26                      409 days
2  000afb96ded6677c    2017-02-19  2017-02-26                      482 days
3  ffea14e87a4e1269    2020-02-18  2020-02-23                        0 days
4  ffea14e87a4e1269    2020-07-18  2020-07-23                      146 days
```

(If `ID` is the index instead of a column `groupby` level=0 instead):

```
df['Time_Difference_Between_Trips'] = (
    (df['Departuredate'] - df.groupby(level=0)['Arrivaldate'].shift())
        .fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=0))
)
```

---

Complete working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['000afb96ded6677c', '000afb96ded6677c', '000afb96ded6677c',
           'ffea14e87a4e1269', 'ffea14e87a4e1269'],
    'Departuredate': ['2014-02-08', '2015-10-22', '2017-02-19', '2020-02-18',
                      '2020-07-18'],
    'Arrivaldate': ['2014-09-08', '2015-10-26', '2017-02-26', '2020-02-23',
                    '2020-07-23']
})
df['Departuredate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Departuredate'])
df['Arrivaldate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Arrivaldate'])

df['Time_Difference_Between_Trips'] = (
    (df['Departuredate'] - df.groupby('ID')['Arrivaldate'].shift())
        .fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=0))
)
print(df)
```